# Compensate for the different values between 0 and 1 in this equation

Tags: equation-solving, programming, probability-or-statistics, subscript

I want a work program to compensate for the different values between 0 and 1 in this equation and show results
[image]

```
Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6]
     Subscript[R, 11] + 
   Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6]
     Subscript[R, 11] `/. Subscript[R, 1] :> 0.95 /. 
 Subscript[R, 2] :> 0.9 /. Subscript[R, 3] :> 0.85 
/.  Subscript[R, 5] :> 0.75 /. Subscript[R, 6] :> 0.7 /.Subscript[R, 11] :> 0.96`
```

So I interpreted like
[image]

But I want to change the values many times and show the results and thus be tired.
Is there a suggestion better than that?

> >

Comment: Well, your images didn't show up correctly, but it doesn't matter anyway: please include your code in your post as typed text, in *Mathematica* syntax, properly formatted in code blocks, rather than as screenshot images.

Comment: @march I've added code

Comment: i guess the think you are looking for is `Table` ? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** full code for a smaller example:

```
exp = Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R,6] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] 
    Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 11]; 

 variables = SortBy[Variables[exp], Last];
 values = Array[Symbol["v" <> ToString[#]] &, Length@Variables[exp]];

 Manipulate[Evaluate[exp /. Thread[variables -> values] // Style[#, 24] &],
 Evaluate[## & @@({{#, .5, ToString[#2, TraditionalForm]}, 0, 1, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"}& @@@Transpose[{values, variables}])], Alignment -> Center]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics] [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

```
variables = SortBy[Variables[expr], Last];
values = Array[Symbol["v" <> ToString[#]] &, Length@Variables[expr]];

Manipulate[Evaluate[expr /. Thread[variables -> values] // Style[#, 24] &],
 Evaluate[## & @@( {{#, .5, ToString[#2, TraditionalForm]}, 0, 1, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"} & @@@ Transpose[{values, variables}])]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

where `expr` is the expression in your posted code before the first `ReplaceAll (/.)`:

```
expr = Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 11] - ...
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: you need to evaluate the piece `expr = ...` before executing the `Manipulate` code.

Update: Copy/paste/execute the following before `Manipulate`:

```
expr = Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 11]+ 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] 
   Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 5] 
    Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5] 
    Subscript[R,6] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] 
    Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R,8] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5]
     Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 4] 
     Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 4] 
     Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R,11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 4]
     Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] 
     Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5] 
     Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 5]
     Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] 
    Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] 
       Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 4] 
     Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5] 
     Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 5]
     Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] 
     Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] 
        Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R,  10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 7] 
     Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 7] 
     Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 4] 
     Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] 
     Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] +
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 5] 
     Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 9] 
        Subscript[R,  10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 4] 
     Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 7] 
        Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 9] 
     Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 9]
     Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R,  8] 
     Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6]
     Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 4] 
     Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 9]
       Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 4] 
     Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 9] 
       Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 8] 
     Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R, 7] 
     Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 4] 
     Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 9] 
        Subscript[R,  10]  Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] 
     Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 9] 
        Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] - 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 4] Subscript[R,5] 
      Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 7] Subscript[R, 8] 
         Subscript[R,  9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11] + 
  Subscript[R, 1] Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3] Subscript[R, 4] 
     Subscript[R, 5] Subscript[R, 6] Subscript[R, 7] 
     Subscript[R, 8] Subscript[R, 9] Subscript[R, 10] Subscript[R, 11];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Table[Replace[a b c d + a f d e, i, {2}], {i, #}] &@
Map[Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f} -> #] &, {{0.95, 0.9, 0.3, 0.85, 0.1, 
0.3}, {0.9, 0.8, 0.2, 0.65, 0.2, 0.1}}]

(* {0.24225, 0.1053} *)
```

Comment: ....But I want the values changed many times

Comment: @Emadkareem instead of posting the long code can you just use something simple like a small dummy example (such as in my code) and explain what you need?